# Move table row to another table on checkbox clicked

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, tablerow

I have trouble with some Javascript code. I have tried a lot of ways to solve it, but anything had helped me.
I simply just want a row from my table 1 to show up in table two, when the checkbox is checked in table 1. Then it has to been removed from table 1.

This is my table 1

```
<label class="collapse" onclick="toggleTableProduct();" href="#" id="productLabel">ProductBacklog</label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="alignButtonAndTable">
    <table id="productTable">
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <tr>
            <th class="itemsth">Name</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Description</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Priority</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Time</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Status</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Add to next table</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Remove from list</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Draw cirle</td>
            <td>Radius 5 cm</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>high</option>
                    <option>medium</option>
                    <option>low</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>ToDo</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="25" id="25" onclick="accept()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my table 2

```
<label class="collapse" onclick="toggleTableSprint();" href="#">SprintBacklog</label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="hidden" id="sprint">
    <table id="sprintTable">
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <tr>
            <th class="itemsth">Name</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Description</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Priority</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Time</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Status</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Add to next table</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Remove from list</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is the code I've last tried to move the row from one to another table.

```
function addRow() {
    if (document.getElementById("25").checked = true) {
        $("#productTable tr").eq(1).insertAfter($("#sprintTable tr").last());
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: The if-statement should use `==`instead of `=`. Alternatively just have it as `if(document.getElementById("25").checked)`

Comment: Still it dosen't work...

Comment: your function name is 'addRow', so checkbox onclick must be addRow() right?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has some hot-button words it won't let us use, one of them is "accept" for functions. Try "accepted":

```js
window.accepted = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("25").checked = true)
        {
            $("#productTable tr").eq(1).insertAfter($("#sprintTable tr").last());
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="collapse" onclick="toggleTableProduct();"
       href="#" id="productLabel">ProductBacklog</label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="alignButtonAndTable">
    <table id="productTable">
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <tr>
            <th class="itemsth">Name</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Description</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Priority</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Time</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Status</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Add to next table</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Remove from list</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Draw cirle</td>
            <td>Radius 5 cm</td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>high</option>
                    <option>medium</option>
                    <option>low</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>ToDo</td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="25" id="25" onclick="accepted()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
            
            <label class="collapse" onclick="toggleTableSprint();"
       href="#">SprintBacklog</label>
<input type="checkbox">
<div class="hidden" id="sprint">
    <table id="sprintTable">
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col>
        <tr>
            <th class="itemsth">Name</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Description</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Priority</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Time</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Status</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Add to next table</th>
            <th class="itemsth">Remove from list</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```